# Use respective child's package's modules when executing bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, webpack

### Setup

I've created a project with 3 npm packages; root, client & server. Each package contains the dependecies they specifically needs; root has build tools, client has react, server has express - you get the idea.

Now... I realize this may be a poor idea since I lose some synergy in having it in the same place but realizing that is part of why I'm doing it.

```
/node_modules
/package.json
/webpack.config.js
/...etc

/dist
├── server-bundle.js
└── client-bundle.js

/client
├── node_modules/
├── package.json
└── src/

/server
├── node_modules/
├── package.json
└── src/
    └── index.ts
```

Webpack config:

```
module.exports = [
  {
    entry: "./client/src/index.tsx",
    mode: "development",
    output: {
      filename: "client-bundle.js",
      path: __dirname + "/dist"
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
    },

    module: {
      noParse: /node_modules/,
      rules: [
        { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" },
        { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
      ]
    },
    externals: {
      "react": "React",
      "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    },
  },
  {
    entry: "./server/src/index.ts",
    mode: "development",
    output: {
      filename: "server-bundle.js",
      path: __dirname + "/dist"
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", "tsx", ".js", ".json"]
    },

    module: {
      noParse: /node_modules/,
      rules: [
        { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" },
      ],
    },
  }
];
```

### Problem

Building and bundling works fine but when starting the server `node dist/server-bundle.js` I get the error that node `Cannot find the modules 'express'` since the root package doesn't have this dependency.

Moving all the dependecies to the root will solve all issues.

### Question

Is there any way to make it work with this structure or am I wrong in my conceptual approach?

Comment: Why are you bundling server code?

Comment: Good point, there is no reason. I guess I wanted all code to go through the same flow (webpack in this case). 

EDIT: A quick google will let you know several benefits of bundling the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your `/dist/`s into the projects, `client/dist/` and `server/dist/` in your case.